# Why are some properties missing when copying object with spread syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here I am spreading the `err` object (which is an `Error` object in Node.js) and cloning it as `error`, but some properties of the `err` object are not copied to `error`.

```
const error = { ...err };
console.log(error.name, error.status, err.name, err.status);
```

The output is:

```
undefined 400 SyntaxError 400
```

Why is `error.name` `undefined`?

Comment: That's spread syntax, not destructuring, FWIW.

Comment: Ya that spread syntax

Comment: Great find @jon!